# Where does a webservice request from a Blazor Server app originate?

Tags: networking, blazor

If I have a blazor server app hosted on a server (Server A) and a client is accessing that server from another device (Client A).

If the Blazor server app is calling a webservice via a System.Net.Http.HttpClient call that is hosted on another server (Server B). Will the request originate from the client device (Client A) or the server hosting the Blazor server app (Server A)?

This has implications for network access requirements as Client may not have access to the webservice hosted on Server B but Server A does?

Comment: Think of ( server A) as a computer that you take control of with some remote control computer software(example: team viewer) installed on (Client A) 
(Server A ) do ALL the work , Client (A) receive just the results. so the requests will originate from server A

Answer (score 0):

With Blazor Server, all c# code is executed on the server, including your web request with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

This differs from Blazor WASM which runs entirely on the client (after the initial request to Server A for the app).